# What do I really want to do today?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

There are so many things I have to do today. One of them is grocery shopping. Hey! Here's my list!

### Meat Department

> Salmon $4.54
>
> Bacon $2.73
>
> Steak $5.88
>
> <s>Ham $7.10</s>
>
> Beef(ground) $3.56

### Bakery

> Baguette $2.00
>
> <s>Muffins $3.18</s>

### Dairy

> Yogurt $3.23
>
> Mozzarella Cheese $2.81<sup>*BOGOF</sup>
>
> Cheddar Cheese $4.51

### Produce

> Apples $2.99-3.99
>
> Cauliflower $3.24
>
> Zucchini $1.32<sup>*BOGOF</sup>
>
> <s>Grapes(Green) $1.03</s>
>
> Lemons $1.03
>
> Beets $2.40

Now,

> **What do I really want to do today?**

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Are you trying to...

> **MAKE A GOOD PUZZLE**?
>
>  This answer can be obtained by indexing into each item by its' price, *ignoring items which are <s>crossed off</s> and taking letters which are [BOGOF](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buy_one,_get_one_free) twice.*
>
>  I'll provide an example of this, using the "dairy" section of the shopping list.
>
>  The first item is yogurt, for \$3.23. This means that we should take the third letter in `YOGURT` , `G`.
>
>  The second item is a buy-one-get-one-free pack of mozzarella cheese for \$2.81. This means that we should take the second letter in `MOZZARELLA CHEESE`, `O`, *twice* (it's BOGOF, who wouldn't take two?)
>
>  The third item is cheddar cheese, for \$4.51. This means that we should take the fourth letter in `CHEDDAR CHEESE`, `d`.
>
>  Doing this for the entire shopping list gives the final answer, **MAKE A GOOD PUZZLE**.

Comment: Here's the check, great job finding the answer :)